# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class x

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, intellij-idea, web-inf

I'm new to tomcat and maven both, I created a project using IntelliJ IDEA.
there are some java classes in src directory, and the .class files is stored in target directory after building the project. It seems that tomcat cannot find where are the .class files to initialize classes. 
here is the directory tree:

[image]

here is my pom.xml contetnt:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>IE</groupId>
  <artifactId>IE</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>IE Maven Webapp</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
      <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp-api</artifactId>
      <version>2.3.1</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
      <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
      <version>4.0.0</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.json</groupId>
      <artifactId>org.json</artifactId>
      <version>chargebee-1.0</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <sourceDirectory>src/main/javaClasses</sourceDirectory>
    <finalName>IE</finalName>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.2</version>
        <configuration>
          <url>http://localhost:8080/manager/text</url>
          <server>TomcatServer</server>
          <path>/projectName</path>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

can anybody help how can I tell the path of target file to find classes please? Now I can't instantiate any of my classes in my jsp files.

Comment: You probably need to show the content of your pom.xml file as well as indicate which class is failing and the  dependency that's supposed to supply it.

Comment: @ErnestKiwele the problem edited. thanks.

Comment: Which class is failing? Is it one of your project classes or is it a class in your dependencies?

Comment: @ErnestKiwele my project classes. their source code is in src/main/java/javaClasses directory.

Comment: Maybe source code should be in the src/main/java package?

Comment: @Rinat I can use java packajes to handle the directory tree on that. couldnt I?

Comment: @Someone please share the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

You haven't customized the configuration of the compiler plugin, therefore, it's incorrect to put your source files under `src/main/javaClasses`.

You should move your source packages/classes to `src/main/java`, and Maven should pick it up. This is where Maven expects them by default.

For more info, check [standard directory layout page](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html).

Comment: I fixed this too. Still there is no response.

Comment: Let us look at maven project building trace please